# collect sparkr into dataframe

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I am loading some data into sparkR (Spark version 1.4.0, running on fedora21) over which I run some algorithm which produces three different numbers. My algorithm takes a bunch of parameters and I want to run over different parameter settings on the same data. The output format should be a dataframe (or a csv list) whose columns are the algorithm parameters and the three numbers my algo computes, i.e.

```
  mypar1, mypar2, mypar3, myres1, myres2, myres3
  1       1.5     1.2     5.6      8.212  5.9
  2       1.8     1.7     5.1      7.78   8.34
```

would be the output for two different parameter settings.
I wrote the script below which parallelises the running over different paramater settings: it takes an input file with parameter values as argument, which for the above example would look like this:

```
 1,1.5,1.2
 2,1.8,1.7
```

so one parameter combination per line.

Here's my problem : Instead of getting one per parameter setting, all the numbers are combined into one long list. The function cv_spark returns a data.frame (basically one row). How can I tell spark to combine the output of cv_spark into a dataframe (i.e. do something like rbind?) or list of list?

```
#!/home/myname/Spark/spark-1.4.0/bin/sparkR

library(SparkR)

sparkcontext <- sparkR.init("local[3]","cvspark",sparkEnvir=list(spark.executor.memory="1g"))

cv_spark <- function(indata) {
   cv_params <- strsplit(indata, split=",")[[1]]
   param.par1 = as.integer(cv_params[1])
   param.par2 = as.numeric(cv_params[2])
   param.par3 = as.numeric(cv_params[3])
   predictions <- rep(NA, 1)
   ## here I run some calculation on some data that I load to my SparkR session, 
   ## but for illustration purpose I'm just filling up with some random numbers
   mypred = base:::sample(seq(5,10,by=0.01),3)
   predictions <- cbind(param.par1, param.par2, param.par3,mypred[1],mypred[2],mypred[3])
   return(as.data.frame(predictions))
}

args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
print(paste("args ", args))
cvpar = readLines(args[[1]])

rdd <- SparkR:::parallelize(sparkcontext, coll=cvpar, numSlices=4)
myerr <- SparkR:::flatMap(rdd,cv_spark)
output <- SparkR:::collect(myerr)
print("final output")
print(output)

outfile = "spark_output.csv"
write.csv(output,outfile,quote=FALSE,row.names=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get what I wanted by using `flatMapValues` instead of `flatMap`, and by creating `(key, value)` pairs of my various parameter settings (basically key is the line number in my parameter input file and value is the parameters on that line). Then I call `reduceByKey` which essentially holds one row per key. The modified script looks like this :

```
#!/home/myname/Spark/spark-1.4.0/bin/sparkR

library(SparkR)

sparkcontext <- sparkR.init("local[4]","cvspark",sparkEnvir=list(spark.executor.memory="1g"))

cv_spark <- function(indata) {
   cv_params <- unlist(strsplit(indata[[1]], split=","))
   param.par1 = as.integer(cv_params[1])
   param.par2 = as.numeric(cv_params[2])
   param.par3 = as.integer(cv_params[3])
   predictions <- rep(NA, 1)
   ## here I run some calculation on some data that I load to my SparkR session, 
   ## but for illustration purpose I'm just filling up with some random numbers
   mypred = base:::sample(seq(5,10,by=0.01),3)
   predictions <- cbind(param.par1, param.par2, param.par3,mypred[1],mypred[2],mypred[3])
   return(as.data.frame(predictions))
}

args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
print(paste("args ", args))
cvpar = readLines(args[[1]])
## Creates (key, value) pairs
cvpar <- Map(list,seq(1,length(cvpar)),cvpar)

rdd <- SparkR:::parallelize(sparkcontext, coll=cvpar, numSlices=1)
myerr <- SparkR:::flatMapValues(rdd,cv_spark)
myerr <- SparkR:::reduceByKey(myerr,"c", 2L)
output <- SparkR:::collect(myerr)

myres <- sapply(output,`[`,2)
df_res <- do.call("rbind",myres)
colnames(df_res) <- c("Element","sigdf","sigq","err","err.sse","err.mse")

outfile = "spark_output.csv"
write.csv(df_res,outfile,quote=FALSE,row.names=FALSE)
```

This works as expected, i.e. the output is a dataframe (or csv file) with same number of rows as in the input file to the above script (i.e. the number of different parameter values configurations), but perhaps there is a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: @Vijay_Shinde `./myexample.R myparameterfile.txt` where myexample.R is the script above. make sure you fix the shebang in your script. myparameterfile.txt contains 3 comma-separated numbers per line.